# Complete? subspace of $R^n$ with $||.||_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be the sequence space of all sequences of the form 
$$ x =(x_1,x_2 ,x_3,\dots , x_n ,0,0 \dots )　$$
where $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$

whose terms are all zero after some index

$(X, || .||_{\infty})$ is a Normed Space  where 
   $$||x||_{\infty} =\max _{i \in \mathbb{N}}|x_i|$$

Prove (or disprove ) if it is a **complete norm space**

---

**Ammo**

**Def complete space**   seq in x that is cauchy then  converges in X

**Def** Cauchy 
$$\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists  N \in \mathbb{N} ; n,m \geq N \Rightarrow || x_n -x_m|| < \epsilon  $$

**Def of convegence in Normed space** $\lim_{n \to \infty }|| x_n||=x$
$$\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists  N \in \mathbb{N} ; n\geq N \Rightarrow || x_n -x|| < \epsilon  $$

> **Prop from Lecture notes**
>
> Let $p \in \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R}^p$  is complete normed vector space
>   if it is equipped with $|| .||_{\infty}$

---

Tried to play with $$
\begin{aligned}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{n} \\ 1 \\  0 \\ \vdots\\0 \end{pmatrix}=x_n &&\text{and} &&x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\  0 \\ \vdots\\0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

I know that $x_n$ is cauchy because ${1/n}$ is cauchy. and
 $$ x_n -x_m = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{m}\\ 0\\  0 \\ \vdots\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
and that should be cauchy. $x_n-x$ seems to converge using the definition of convergence. because

$$x_n-x =\begin{pmatrix} 1/n \\ 0 \\\ 0\\\ \vdots   \end{pmatrix}$$

Having trouble coming up with a sequence that is cauchy  in X and does not convege in X.

Want to say that since $(R^p,|| .||_\infty)$ is complete and $X \subset R^p$ then $X$ is complete but dont know  that can be said.

---

Comment: There is also another (slightly more advanced) ammo which can be used to prove something even stronger: *Theorem: The dimension of every Banach space is uncountable.* Your space  $X=c_{00}$ has a countable Hamel basis, so there is no norm on $X$ which can make it a complete space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example $x_n= (1,1/2,\dots,1/n,0,\dots)$. Then $x_n$ is Cauchy, and $x_n\to x$ in $\ell_{\infty}$ sense where $x=(1,1/2,1/3,...,1/n,1/(n+1),\dots)$ but $x\notin X$.